# How to insert database values into the template stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, python, css, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a pyramid app where I insert an entry in my database table on a Zope page template. The chameleon template engine renders it to html. What I want to do is move this entry over by the value column in the database associated with the entry. Here is what I would want to do.

```
<html>
<p class="entries">${entry.name}</p>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
.entries {
    margin-left: var(entry.value) px;
}
</style>
```

obviously this is incorrect. Is there a way to do this with JQuery custom css classes perhaps? I don't know how to integrate it with the pyramid framework or the sqlalchemy ORM.

Comment: isn't it ${entry.value}?

Comment: yep you are correct. I didn't know if it was different because its a style sheet but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is exactly the same in the style sheet as it would be in the rest of the template. You just need to use ${} format. I am not sure what you would do if you wanted to put the css in a separate file though.

Comment: In html template (using mako)...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${request.route_url('css', foo="bar", cat="dog", etc="etc")}"/>

then you can do
    config.add_view('path.to.view.callable', template="package:templates/css/screen.css.mako",
route_name='css')